# PHP - Why my logic statement don't work right?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a Account.txt file with information about Email and Password like

```
Email01|Password01
Email02|Password02
...
EmailN|PasswordN
```

I read this file and stored into an array

```
<?php

    $myFile = fopen("Account.txt","r") or die("Unable to open file!");

    //An array for the key of data
    $keyData = array('Email','Password');
    // Array store all data
    $allAccountData = array();
    while(!feof($myFile)) { 
        $line = fgets($myFile);

        $dataValue = explode('|', $line);
        $accountData = array_combine($keyData, $dataValue);
        array_push($allAccountData, $accountData);

    }

    fclose($myFile);
   ?>
```

And I checked input data from form like

```
<?php 
        if(empty($user_login)) 
            include "form-register.php";        
        else {
            $flag = false;

            foreach($allAccountData as $key=>$value) {
                if($value['Email'] == $user_login and $value['Password'] == $user_password) {
                    $flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($flag == true) {
                echo "<p align = 'center'> <strong> Welcome ".$user_login." to facebook!</strong>"."<br>";
                echo "Click <a href='index.php'> here to logout </p>";  
            }
            else {
                echo "<p align = 'center' <strong> Sorry your login information is wrong!</strong>"."<br>";
                echo "Click <a href='index.php'> here to login again </p>";
            } 

        }

    ?>
```

I wonder why the result `$flag = true` only return for the last line `EmailN|PasswordN` and return `false` for other line whether the input is correct, and
Is any good way to store data which read from file except use Array.

Sorry my English is not good and thank you guys so much!

Comment: what's the output of $allAccountData?

Comment: _“I wonder why”_ - stop _wondering_, and start _debugging_. Make debug outputs of the values you script operates with, and check the results. Add `var_dump($value['Password'], $user_password);` inside your foreach loop. Check the result carefully, you should note a significant difference between what happens with the last line, and all those before it.

Comment: not the answer for your request but you can simplify your file read mechanism. Look at the file() function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.file.php

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [Email] => Email01 [Password] => Password01 ) [1] => Array ( [Email] => Email02 [Password] => Password02 ) )`
like that

Comment: Mybad didn't check carefully ,didn't regconize the datatype of my data. Thanks a lot @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to trim white spaces before comparing.

```
$flag = false;

foreach($allAccountData as $key=>$value) 
{

    if(trim($value['Email']) == 'Email01' && trim($value['Password']) == 'Password01') 
    {
        $flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($flag == true) 
{
    echo "<p align = 'center'> <strong> Welcome  to facebook!</strong>"."<br>";
    echo "Click <a href='index.php'> here to logout </p>";  
}
else 
{
    echo "<p align = 'center' <strong> Sorry your login information is wrong!</strong>"."<br>";
    echo "Click <a href='index.php'> here to login again </p>";
}
```

Using [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) removes all the possible white spaces from before and after the value being compared and makes comparison more accurate.

Using trim, the logic is working.